# How can I export an SSIS diagram as part of my SSIS build step?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, continuous-integration, teamcity, build-process

Is it even possible to programmatically export an SSIS package's flow diagrams from outside of Visual Studio?

We're setting up our SSIS project for automatic builds inside a TeamCity server using devenv.exe (per [this walkthrough](https://kzhendev.wordpress.com/2015/10/12/building-and-packaging-sql-server-integration-services-projects-in-teamcity/)). I'd like to make a build step that exports the Control and/or Data Flow diagrams.

Thanks ahead of time for any advice. All the responses I see when I search the web are suggestions to just screencap inside VS :/

Comment: Screen grab is all there is, the `diagram` itself is just how VS visual displays it based on the order and precedents in the package itself.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing built in or easy that does this.

If you're feeling ambitious you could write a script task that does it.

You can do pretty much anything with a script task.